# Problem with this SQL that finds duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me with a problem with this SQL in phpmyadmin that finds duplicate records for cleanup:

```
SELECT userid, MIN(logged_time),`logged_time`, count(email) as duplicated_count 
FROM tbl_users 
GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1 
ORDER BY `duplicated_count` DESC
```

Here is the GOAL:

- Trying to list the duplicate email records in a user database that also tracks when they last used the system under the account.
- Trying to identify the records with the oldest logged_time so those duplicates ONLY can be deleted.

PROBLEM:

The SQL above WORKS to identify the duplicates.  AND, it WORKS to display the oldest (min) login. BUT>>>  The one userID it returns is NOT the user id with the oldest login.

In other words, the data returned is from different records in the duplicate search for the same user email.

The results look like:

```
userid, MIN(logged_time), logged time, 
"111"  "2013-04-10 22:35:21",  "2017-10-01 04:17:49"
```

SO......   User "111" is not the one I want to delete!  That `userid` matches the most RECENT logged time.  I want the `userid` for the record that matched `MIN(logged_time)`.

Thanks for the help!  I know this may be confusing.

MySQL version is 5.5, so the code posted doesn't seem to work with this version.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how to connect all the fields displayed for a duplicate record together so they are from the SAME duplicate record?

Comment: Edit the question and 1) show all table DDL, complete sample data, expected output

Comment: Why are you grouping by email, but selecting the userid. If you want an unique userid you should group by(userid).  Or do you have a system where the same user can have multiple different userid values, using only 1 email?

Comment: Can your MySql use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)?

Comment: Your query is not legal SQL, it leads to exactly the problem you're having. But MySQL allows it. [Here's an explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). `MIN(logged_time)` does not constrain the query, it just gives the oldest `logged_time` in the group.

Comment: What version of MySQL (I assume it's MySQL) are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.5... which means I can't use your solution as is.

Comment: Another solution that I would be ok with would be something that outputs ALL of the rows in the table for records with duplicate emails.  At least then I could perhaps sub-sort on logged)time and do some manual work on it to clean it up...

Comment: To Answer MTilsted's question:  user_id is the primary key.  We fixed the system a while ago to prevent duplicate emails. But we have to clean it up now.  So we have to identify which user_id's to delete (which should be the duplicates that have the oldest login)

Answer (score 1):

> The one userID it returns is NOT the user id with the oldest login.

Selecting `min(logged_time)` does not say to only return the oldest login. It just gives you the oldest logged_time for each email.

What you asked for is invalid SQL, but MySQL allows it. It's invalid because it leads to exactly the trouble you're having.

Say we have this.

```
userid   email    logged_time
-----------------------------
1        email1   2021-01-01
2        email2   2021-01-01
3        email1   2021-02-01
4        email3   2021-01-01
```

If we `select userid, min(logged_time), count(email) from tbl_users group by email`, MySQL can only show you one row per email. For email2 and email3 that's fine, there's only one option. But for email1 it has to choose either 1 or 3.

Normally this would make the query invalid and you would get an error. You can't select a non-aggregated column (userid) which is not in the group by.

But MySQL allows this. It picks a userid at random. And we get the problem you're having.

```
userid   min(logged_time) count(email)
--------------------------------------
2        2021-01-01       1
3        2021-01-01       2
4        2021-01-01       1
```

See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for more, and I'd suggest you turn it off with [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

---

What you're asking for is a bit tricky.

You need to both find emails with duplicates AND pick the oldest row for each email. You can't do all that in a single query, you need two queries joined together.

You know how to find duplicate emails.

```
-- Note that if you have two entries with the same userid and email
-- it will count that as a duplicate.
select email
from tbl_users
group by email
having count(email) > 1
```

To order the emails by their logged_time use the [row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) [window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/).

```
select
  userid,
  email,
  logged_time,
  row_number() over(partition by email order by logged_time asc) as login_order
from tbl_users
```

That will return all the rows with each ranked.

```
userid   email    logged_time   login_order
--------------------------------------------
1        email1   2021-01-01     1
2        email2   2021-01-01     1
3        email1   2021-02-01     2
4        email3   2021-01-01     1
```

Join them together and select only where login_order = 1.

```
-- Get the emails with dups.
with users_with_duplicates as (
    select email
    from tbl_users
    group by email
    having count(email) > 1
),
-- Get the logins by email ranked by ascending logged_time
users_in_login_order as (
  select
    userid,
    email,
    logged_time,
    row_number() over(partition by email order by logged_time asc) as login_order
  from tbl_users
)
select
  users_in_login_order.*
from users_in_login_order
-- The join will constrain users_in_login_order to only emails with dups
join users_with_duplicates
  on users_in_login_order.email = users_with_duplicates.email
where login_order = 1
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19b0b59485ab73d8a5a8fcf4073a6ae9).

Comment: This is brilliant!  However, much of this query doesn't work because I'm on MySQL 5.5... Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you help with code that would work for MySQL 5.5?

Comment: @user2416038 Upgrade. MySQL 5.5 was end-of-lifed 3 years ago. At least to 5.7 so you have security fixes. MySQL 8 brought a lot of new features. If you can't upgrade: the CTEs can be done as subqueries, and [row_number can be emulated using variables](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).